# How to get Java 6 JDK on mavericks

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to get the Java 6 JDK on my mac. I've tried downloading this http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

But I can't find it in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

I already have Java 8 installed, and I don't want to remove it or replace it, I just want to have the Java 1.6 JDK that I can work with on my computer. (Need it to do my mandatory assignemtns for class. Studying Computer Science)

What do I have to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem with just using compliance level 1.6 with the 1.8 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

It installs in a different location.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Yoyo-2.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386 MacBookPro11,3 Darwin

$ /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```